# Jest snapshot test ignores child styling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, testing, jestjs

I am trying to write a simple snapshot test for a very, very simple react-native component. However, the snapshot used by Jest does not contain any styling or content information for the component's single child.

The component is a button from native-base with an icon in it. Source:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Button, Icon } from 'native-base';
export default class AddButton extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Button transparent
            style={{
              alignSelf: "center",
              paddingTop: 0,
              paddingBottom: 0}}>
        <Icon
            style={{fontSize: 36}}
            name="ios-add-circle-outline" />
    </Button>);
  }
}
```

And here's the test for it:

```
import React from 'react';
import AddButton from './AddButton.js';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer
    .create(<AddButton/>)
    .toJSON();
  console.log(tree);
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

The snapshot looks like this:

```
<View
  // ... lots of properties
  style={
    Object {
      // ... lots of styles
    }
  }
>
  // But no info about the Text component below!
  <Text />
</View>
```

All that is there for the Text components is the barebones `<Text />`. It should contain the `fontSize` style and it should have an icon text in it!

How do I create a snapshot for the component that includes all of the style and text of its children?

Comment: where is `<Text />` in your `<AddButton />`? and btw there is nothing about Jest and its `toMatchSnapshot`. it's 100% about react-test-renderer and how it handles `<Text/ >`

Comment: and btw#2 Jest displays exactly same case in [its docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react-native#snapshot-test) with `react-test- renderer` and `<Text />` having styles. So this could be an issue related to specific version whether of `react-native` or `react-test-renderer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by Expo's rendering logic for icons. The icon fonts are loaded in the background, and if the icon component is rendered before the font finishes loading, the component is rendered as simply `<Text />`. See https://github.com/expo/vector-icons/blob/master/createIconSet.js#L39.

I opened https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/3566 to get a note about this added to the documentation.